# Unable to see scope variable in angular

Tags: angularjs, django, angularjs-scope

i am trying to use django with angular js

here is the controller myHeader.js

```
var myHeader = angular.module('myHeader', []);

myHeader.controller('HeaderController' , ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.PasswordReset = function(){
        $scope.message = "done";
    };
}]);
```

then i have included this controller in the header.html

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/libs/angular.min.js' %}"></script>

<!-- Angular Includes -->

<script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/controllers/myHeader.js' %}"></script>

<body ng-app="myHeader">
<div id="forgotPass" ng-controller="HeaderController">

                        <h4 class="modal-title text-center" style="font-size:18px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;"><strong>Change Password</strong> </h4>

                        <div id="div_id_email" class="form-group required">
                        <div class="controls ">
                        <form id="password_reset" action="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}" method="POST" novalidate ng-submit="PasswordReset()"> 
                        {% csrf_token %}
                            <input class="emailinput form-control" id="id_email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" style="margin-bottom:10px" ng-model="user.email" ng-required="true"/> 
                            {{message}}

                            <div>
                            <input class='btn btn-block btn-primary pull-left' id="pass-btn" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" style="width: 63%" />
                            <input class='btn btn-block btn-primary pull-right' style="width:34%; margin-top: 0px; background-color: #757575; border: 1px solid #616161;" value="Cancel" id="canPass"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="error-box">
                            <div class="err2"></div>                        
                            <div class="ajax-sign"><img src="/static/images/ajax1.gif" height="30px"></div>
                        </div>
                        </form> 
                        </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
</body>
```

the above header.html file is being included in base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% include 'products/header.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

With the Above i am unable to see the scope variable message value when i submit the form.
How can i get rid of the above problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing regular forms and AJAX is a common pitfall. I suggest for you to read a bit on the documentation about ng-submit and using forms in Angular.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action

> Since the role of forms in client-side Angular applications is
>   different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the
>   browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload
>   that sends the data to the server. Instead some javascript logic
>   should be triggered to handle the form submission in an
>   application-specific way.

When submitting a form it causes a full page reload, so your controller is re-initialised and its $scope.message doesn't exist.
If you want to prevent the default form submit action, you should remove the "action" and "method" from your form definition, and do an AJAX call instead (upon ng-submit callback)..